# How to show asp.net validation on button click event if i have 200 checkboxes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, validation

How to show asp.net validation on button click event if i have 200 checkboxes and some of the checkboxes would be disabled and some are unchecked ... if user doesn't check any of the checkbox then asp.net validation control will display and user will be stay at the same page until they check any of the unchecked checkbox ...

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ValidationGroup property.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" ValidationGroup="Save" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" ValidationGroup="Save" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" ValidationGroup="Save" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>                      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" ValidationGroup="Save" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />